# Read "date" from excel file using Interop Excel.Application

Tags: vb.net, interop, excel-interop

I am reading and fetching information from excel file using interop but I faced one problem that when I read date from my excel file. 02/05/2012; It gives 41060.

How can I read proper date value or why it returns 41060?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found your answer but some background might help.

Excel holds dates and times as numbers. If a user types 31-May-2012 into a cell, Excel recognises this as a date so stores the value as 41060 and sets the number format to "dd-mmm-yyyy". If a user types 41060 into a cell and sets the number format to "dd-mmm-yyyy", the value will be displayed as 31-May-2012. Once the data entry is finished, Excel does not record that the first 41060 was entered as a date and the second as a number.

On a PC, the integer part of a date is days since the year 1900 (On a Mac the year 1904 is used) and the decimal part is:

```
time in seconds
---------------
seconds in day
```

So 41060.25 represents: 31 May 2012 6:00:00

When reading data via the Excel InterOp, I suggest you get `.NumberFormat` as well as `.Value` if you do not know the type of the data.  `.Text` might also be useful; it gives the value the user sees.

Warning: if you do get `.NumberFormat`, the formats used by Excel are slightly different from the formats used by VBA's Format() and from VB.Net's Format().

Visit [How to use dates and times in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214094) for more detail on Excel dates.

Answer (score 3):

I found that it returns date in double so doing DateTime.FromOADate(41060) will return proper formatted date.

Comment: I will have a try with your solution. :)